# How to setup F3 .htaccess with MAMP on Mac?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mamp, fat-free-framework

I recently switched my OS from Windows to Mac and I am having a problem running locally. I installed MAMP under /Applications/MAMP.

/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /abc/

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule (.+\.(?:gif|png|jpe?g|css|js|woff|ttf))$ /abc/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule .* /abc/index.php [L]
```

This fully worked on my Windows environment but now it only loads some of the resources and throws the following error:

```
Not Found (404) - HTTP 404 (GET /index.php)

array(1) {
[0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["file"]=>
    string(42) "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/abc/index.php"
    ["line"]=>
    int(27)
    ["function"]=>
    string(3) "run"
    ["class"]=>
    string(4) "Base"
    ["type"]=>
    string(5) "->"
    ["args"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

My Network shows it is trying to GET localhost:8888/abc/index.php but it is receiving a 404, even though that is the correct path.

I am fairly certain this is an error with my .htaccess file because my images and fonts are loading correctly.

Comment: It does not. It exists `Applications\MAMP\htdocs\abc`

Comment: The file that displays the error is `Applications\MAMP\htdocs\abc\views\error.html`

Comment: Applications/MAMP/htdocs/abc/index.php exists

Comment: Nothing changed, same exact error in both the ui and network

Comment: As in, the array being printed is still there with same information and my network trace still shows a 404 on when it tries to GET `localhost:8888/abc/index.php`.

Comment: Sorry, i should have specified. This what is loading when I go directly to `localhost:8888/abc/index.php`. Nothing loads when I go to `localhost:8888/abc/`. Which F3 should automatically route to index.php.

Comment: Add `DirectoryIndex index.php` at top of your .htaccess for that

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much. If you add an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translating my comments into an answer.

Looks like the error is due to the fact the `index.php` is not loading by default for a folder. You need to place this line at top of your .htaccess.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```